# How can I put this array to multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is some example of my code

```
$data = array('code'=>'100','txt'=>'success');
$movie = array('name'=>'movie', array(array('id'=>'1','name'=>'movie1'),array('id'=>'2','name'=>'movie2')));
$anime = array('name'=>'anime', array(array('id'=>'1','name'=>'anime1'),array('id'=>'2','name'=>'anime2')));;
```

How can I put $movie and $anime into $data['data'] ? 
I try array_push and `$data['data'] = array($movie,$anime);` `or $data['data'][] = array($movie,$anime);` and it didnt work.

oh sorry I just want it to xml ( I have function that convert array to xml )

now I use $data['data']['item'][] = array($movie,$anime);

so here's my xml

```
<xml>
<data>
<item>[movie]</item>
<item>[anime]</item>
</data>
<xml>
```

my question is , Is there another way to put it to data without  ?

Comment: `$data['data'] = array($movie,$anime);` should have worked.

Comment: See this demo http://ideone.com/bMjZYt

Comment: Oh looks like it's my mistake. I try to make it like <data>[movie][anime]</data> and it looks like it cant do it , or not ?

Comment: I'm not even sure what that means. You want to put arrays in HTML `<data>` tags?

Comment: Please edit your question, showing what you want the resulting PHP variable to be.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this:

```
$data['data'] = array($movie, $anime]);
```

Using the short array syntax, it's even easier:

```
$data['data'] = [$movie, $anime];
```

If you're doing this inside a loop, then add them one at a time:

```
$data['data'] = array();
$data['data'][] = $movie;
$data['data'][] = $anime;
```

Or if you want to use [`array_push()`](http://php.net/array_push):

```
$data['data'] = array();
array_push($data['data'], $movie);
array_push($data['data'], $anime);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/137743)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to understand how `array_push` works. It will insert an element to the **end** of the array and it will give it a numeric key based on the highest numeric key available. If there are no numeric keys (eg all text), then the numeric key will be zero.

For example:

```
php > $a = array('b','c');
php > array_push($a, 'd');
php > print_r($a);
Array
(
    [0] => b
    [1] => c
    [2] => d
)
```

All keys in the above example are letters because we haven't create an associative array. But if we do create an associative array, it will look like:

```
php > $b = array('a'=>'a');
php > array_push($b, 'c');
php > print_r($b);
Array
(
    [a] => a
    [0] => c
)
```

If you use `array_push` or `array_shift` on the `$data` array, you will **add** the data you want to add but without an associative array index, something that you can refer to, in this case 'data'.

To add, you can do:

```
$data['data'] = array($movie, $anime);
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends, do you want both anime and movie arrays in one key of the main array, or in separate ones example:

```
$data['anime'] = $anime;
$data['move'] = $movie;
```

Would be accessed like $data['anime']['name'];
etc, or you could put them both under data, like your question implies like so

```
$data['data'] = array($anime, $movie);
```

Which could be accessed like $data['data'][1]['name'] for the movie array, and 0 for the anime array.